# Using code from framework without linking it

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, cocoa-touch

I am building a cocoa touch framework and including in my code third party framework - "framework_X"

How can i use it in a way that "framework_X" will not be linked directly to my framework, instead it will require the consumer project which use my framework to link "framework_X" to his project in order for it to work.

In Android this is done easily, but in Xcode if i am not linking the "framework_X" in my framework the project won't build

Answer (score 0):

You can load libraries at runtime. Here an example of loading zlib with dlopen():

https://github.com/nicklockwood/GZIP/blob/master/GZIP/GZIP.m